# Part of my object doesn't show it's texture in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

[image: black texture]

Hello, I'm a beginner in Blender and i found this problemm while trying to preview my object's texture in cycles. Part of my object doesn't show it's texture. I have checked the normals and there is no problem in it. I tried Eevee rendering and the texture shows up, it also shows up in material preview.
Maybe you guys can find some solution. Thank you in Advance :)

Comment: There's something I don't understand: why are you plugging the image texture into the Principled Normal socket? If you want to create bumps, you need to plug a Vector > Bump node before the Normal socket. It may be your problem...

Comment: Oh right, that is actually my problem. Silly me. Thank you for helping me man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you've plugged your *Image Texture* into the *Normal* socket of your *Principled BSDF*. It's not the way it works, you need at least to put a *Vector > Bump* map between these 2 nodes, and ideally it's better to use a b&w height picture, created from your original picture with a software like CrazyBump or else...

Comment: Thank you for helping me :) it works.